Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind' when calling function from kv langauge
I'm trying to call this function in the main app class after this button is pressed in the kv language but I keep getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind' and I don't know why. I've tried googling it but none of the solutions for that error worked for me. My code's shown below (I've just left in the app class code and button code). Any help is appreciated!
class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_string(""" <CorrectScreen>:
    name: "correct"

    Button:
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (102/255.0, 255/255.0, 0, 1)
        font_size: 42
        text: "Correct!"
        on_release:
            app.stop()
            app.again()""")
    def again(self):
        print("hi")


I think you just need to move the call of app.again() before the call of app.stop() so that app is not None when app.again() is called.

Oh my god that's it. I'm such an idiot, thank you so much!
